# Update version number in parent tag

Tags: maven, svn, tortoisesvn, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Before marking the question duplicate, request you to please go through it completly:

I am working in trunk branch,I want to cut a new branch whose version would be decided by some random calcuation at run time and I have to use that version number in my branch.
I want to update the version in the parent tag present in the child pom, automatically when I create a branch through maven.
Below is the child pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.trial.one</groupId>
    <artifactId>trial1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- update this number -->
</parent>
```

Project Design:
1) Parent pom has no reference to the child pom using the xml tag

```
<module>
```

2) Child pom has no reference path to the parent, only the above parent tag.
3) I tried maven release plugin(prepare&release)/version:set/update-versions but none of them could actually update the version in the parent tag. Both commands update the version in the child's version number only & not the parent tag

Can you please provide a solution using which, when a branch is cut out using release:prepare/release:perform or release:branch, when I key-in the version number, that version number should be update in parent tag version number present in child's pom.xml

Comment: I do not completely get your project design, but maybe you should look into http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-parent.html

Comment: where have you called `update-versions`? In the Directory of parent or child Project?